# Failure for ordinal distributive law from the right

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

It is well known that for ordinals $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ one has that

$$\alpha\cdot(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha \cdot \beta + \alpha \cdot \gamma$$

To show this, let $B$, $C$ be disjoint sets with respective order types $β, γ$ and $A$ a set of
order-type $α$. The two orderings of $A × (B ∪ C)$ agree, namely $A×(B∪C)=(A×B)∪(A×C)$

However, doesn't the same thing hold on the left, namely
$$(B∪C)×A=(B×A)∪(C×A)$$

since I feel like the exact same argument would work.

But that then implies $$(\beta+\gamma)\cdot\alpha= \beta \cdot \alpha + \alpha \cdot \gamma$$

which is false.

Where does my argument go wrong?

Comment: Note that the definition of $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is the lexicographic order type of $\beta\times\alpha$, not that of $\alpha\times\beta$.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I still can't see it. Is the problem with the second identity I'm using or is it with the idea as a whole?

Comment: Well, for starters the definition you claim to be using is wrong. It gives you the result you claim is false, and disproves the result you claim is true. How's that for a root of a problem?

Comment: That makes sense now. Also, thanks a lot in general - you've answered very nice quite a few of my questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that neither ordinal addition nor ordinal multiplication is commutative.

The definition of $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is the order type of $\beta\times\alpha$ in the lexicographic order. It is true that $(B\cup C)\times A$ is isomorphic to $(B\times A)\cup(C\times A)$. But it is no longer necessarily the case that $(A\times B)\cup (A\times C)$ is isomorphic to $A\times (B\cup C)$.

To understand why, note that the lexicographic ordering on $X\times Y$ is given by replacing each point $x\in X$ by a copy of $Y$. This action is *not* commutative. Replacing each point in $\omega$ by two points, will again be $\omega$. Replacing two points by two copies of $\omega$ is *not* the same as $\omega$ itself.

Therefore, the obvious bijections that you have there are not order preserving. So the whole argument falls apart.

Comment: Just a general (hopefully final) question - does this have to do with the fact that when defining ordered pairs we have that the second entry is $\{x,y\}$ and that's why only $1$ of the identities hold?

Comment: No. You could define ordered pairs as $(x,y)=\{\{x,y\},\{y\}\}$ just as well. This is a consequence of how you define the lexicographic ordering as "first compare the left coordinate, if there is equality, move on to the second coordinate".

Comment: To the OP: There is no 1st or 2nd entry in $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}.$ It's not an ordered set, just a set with 1 or 2 members. It's just the way most people prefer to write the list of the members.